# shadowsocks error connecting from 127.0.0.1:37314

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, connection

I use Ubuntu in the GFW in China and I installed shadowsocks-qt5. After I set the  server configuration file,and connect the server, I cannot connect to google.com.

I checked the server configuration,and it is correct.

I checked the log. it shows:

```
    TCP server listen at port 1080
    Connecting 93.46.8.89:80 from 127.0.0.1:37306
    Connecting 93.46.8.89:80 from 127.0.0.1:37310
    Connecting 93.46.8.89:80 from 127.0.0.1:373014
```

My local port in configuration is 1080, I cannot understand why it connects from the port 37306, and still it changes the port.

I installed shadowsocks before installing shadowsocks-qt5,and finally removed shadowsocks.

I then removed the shadowsocks-qt5 with command purge and installed it again and it is still there.

I guess that maybe it has something wrong in server configuration because I set two server configurations in shadowsocks before I removed shadowsocks, or maybe these are read by shadowsocks-qt5.

But I have no way to find where the server configuration is?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with the port, it is the APP that not working properly.

My solution is using the command line app instead (https://portal.shadowsocks.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=10). E.g. with python + pip installed, type

```
sudo pip install shadowsocks
sslocal -s sg01-22.ssv4.net -p 22222 -b 127.0.0.1 -l 1080 -k password -m aes-256-cfb
```

Here, items following **-s,-p,-k** should be changed to your **server url, server port, password**. You may need a shortcut by adding this line to your `~/.bashrc` file, so you can start it by typing `myvpn`:

```
alias myvpn="nohup sslocal -s sg01-22.ssv4.net -p 22222 -b 127.0.0.1 -l 1080 -k password -m aes-256-cfb >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

Also, AutoProxy for Firefox is poorly maintained, I suggest to use **chromium + Proxy SwitchySharp** instead.
see https://ttt.tt/150/ for details of browser setting.

Answer (score 0):

`google.com` is polluted by GFW, and `93.46.8.89` is not Google's server. You should try to resolve hostname through your proxy, by using `http` or `socks5h` proxy protocol.
e.g.

```
ALL_PROXY=socks5h://127.0.0.1:1080 curl -vv https://www.google.com/robots.txt
```

PS. There is nothing to do with the port, since `37306` is source port of your client. Your server is working fine.